# Add controls to a messagebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, messagebox

Is it possible to add buttons or maybe other controls to an existing message box? It would be very use full instead of making a form.
If it’s not possible for an existing message box, is it possible to make a new component like that?

PS: I'm using win forms. And I know that you can add the yes/no buttons. Like this:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //do something
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Thanks already!

Comment: UserControl is your solution.

Comment: You cannot override the messagebox, but you can make your own messagebox form that works pretty much the same way

Comment: Alright, I will try to use a UserControl. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well*, the answer you are looking for is NO. It is not possible to add other controls to `MessageBox`. If the current [`MessageBoxButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) enum doesn't provide you with your required buttons then you have no other option then to make your own, using a standard `Form` or a [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You may see : [Custom Message Box in VC#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327212/Custom-Message-Box-in-VC) as a starting point.

Comment: @Downvoter, Could you please point to the mistake in the answer ?

Comment: Thanks for your solution I tried it and it is exactly what I needed!